# Recommended standards for unit test failure messages?

Tags: unit-testing

This is a rather minor aspect of unit testing, but I'm curious about the (often optional) failure message that you can define to display in the event that a test assertion fails during test execution.  **Are there recommended practices for when to use such messages and what information to include in them?**

For example, I'd guess that not every assertion needs to have a failure message defined, namely, when it's quite clear what the expected outcome of the test is supposed to be.  But there are those instances when you might want to test a few aspects of an object after doing a single action, meaning that you may have a couple assertions listed in one test method.  Should each assertion in that scenario have a descriptive failure message, so that it's easy to see why the test method might have failed at a given point?

Comment: Maybe not an answer to your question, more a tip, but if you use Hamcrest matchers instead of old school asserts the messages are a lot nicer by default and there is rarely a need for providing a custom message. Edit: Thought I was in the Java tag, my comment is very Java specific...

Comment: No problem, thanks for the pointer!  I work mostly in C#, but I've had this same question in other languages, too, so I left it language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found custom failure message helpful in rather limited number of cases. Particulary, when you assert several properties of objects which *expected/actual* values might not give the best information about what (and why) failed. Consider a test such as:

```
[Test]
public void CreateOrder_CreatesValidOrderForProvidedCustomer()
{
    // Assume we arranged test here

    var order = orderFactory.Create(customer);

    Assert.That(order.Type, Is.EqualTo("Immediate Dispatch"));
    Assert.That(order.Details, Is.EqualTo("Very Important Package"));
    Assert.That(order.CustomerNote, Is.EqualTo("Send fast or I tell mom"));
}
```

When any of the asserts above fails, message you'll get will be something along the lines:

> *Expected: "Very Important Package" Actual: "Dispatch quickly"*.

It's hard to tell *which* property caused that without looking at unit test (data it uses to be precise). Simply adding **property name** as a failure message helps here.

But!

This was just extreme case, when multiple asserted properties might be hard to differentiate *content-wise*. Usually, you shouldn't be facing such problems (note that we solved it with providing ***one*** word long expection message). If you feel the need to use long and descriptive expection message, it might be a sign that your test is overly complicated. You might consider splitting it into few tests, or maybe even redesigning tested class.

On top of that, I suggest having a look at projects like [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/). They got it right:

> Nothing is more annoying then a unit test that fails without clearly explaining why.

And solved the issue with very clean syntax and neat error reporting:

```
"1234567890".Should().Be("0987654321");
```

Will be reported as:

> Expected string to be
>   "0987654321", but
>   "1234567890" differs near "123" (index 0).

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons are very useful for determining what went wrong. The JUnit failure messages are in the standard form:

I expected `this`, but I got `this`.

It is even better if you can show the diff marks.